# DBSCAN eps parameter in meter

Tags: python-3.x, dbscan

I have a bunch of simple lat-lon coordinates and I'd like to identify hot-spots in a city with the help of DBSCAN. I'm unsure about setting up the eps parameter and i haven't found any answers yet. I use the following code to adjust the epsilon threshold to 5 meter:

```
earth_radius_km = 6371
# calculating 5 meter epsilon threshold 
epsilon = 5 / earth_radius_km

clusterer = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon,
            min_samples = 10 
            )
```

The result is quiet correct but there are differences between points that are greater than 5 meter. What is the correct way to determine the eps parameter in meters?

Answer (score 0):

Knn elbow to determine eps

you will need to convert your points to radians first for this to work. The following psuedocode should do the trick:

```
points = np.array([[lat1, lon1], [lat2, lon2], ...]) 
rads = np.radians(points) 
clusterer = dbscan.DBSCAN(min_samples=N, metric='haversine')
cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(points)
```

Comment: I don’t need to find the optimal eps value, I need to convert 5 meters to eps value. This method can be a good solution: 

eps_in_meters = 5
earth_perimeter = 40070000.0  # In meters
epsilon = eps_in_meters / earth_perimeter * (2 * math.pi)